# How to propagate mouse event from QMenuBar to the parent QMainWindow?

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to implement a frameless window. I wrote some functions in my window class to handle drag and drop mouse events. However, my window class does not receive mouse events when I drag the menu. How can I propagate the mouse events to the window class?

The .h file:

```
class MyWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MyWindow();

private:
    Ui::DeblurSoftwareWinClass ui;

protected:
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *e);
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *e);
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e);
    QPoint window_drag_start_pos;
};
```

The .cpp file:

```
MyWindow::MyWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
}

MyWindow::~MyWindow()
{}

void MyWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e) {
    if (!isMaximized() &&
        e->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
        window_drag_start_pos = e->pos();
    }
}

void MyWindow::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *e) {
    window_drag_start_pos = QPoint(0, 0);
}

void MyWindow::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *e) {
    if (!window_drag_start_pos.isNull()) {
        move(pos() + e->pos() - window_drag_start_pos);
    }
}
```

The `QMenuBar` object is created by default when I created the project.

Comment: Hi, can you show us some of your code ?

Comment: `QObject::installEventFilter`